# Htaccess - exception

Tags: .htaccess

I have some problem with my Mod Rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/index.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^indexl.php$ - [L]
```

I want to make an exception only for 2 files admin.php and login.php.
If I type xxx.com/admin.php then will be not displayed xxx.com/admin but like source file admin.php

Answer (score 0):

Just below `RewriteBase /` insert this new rule to ignore 2 php files:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:admin|login)\.php$ - [L,NC]
```